# How to render html text from database inside a django template using template tags

Tags: django, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I save a text into my database using django form, textarea widget and bootstrap wysiwyg, but when I try to render it into my template using just the variable name

```
{{ text }},
```

I get rendered just the text with html tags like this:
 [image: shows the rendering of html tags]

what I want to do is show the formatted text in html.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have the formatted HTML in your DB-field, and you absolutely sure is it safe, then try `safe` filter

```
{{ tablename.fieldname|safe }}
```

or

```
{{var|safe}}
```

See the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe).